# Si no encuentra un valor en el filtro de la tabla dinámica que arroje un valor "sin datos"?

Tags: excel, vba, macros, visual-basic

Tengo el siguiente problema. Me entregaron una planilla para automatizar los graficos dinamicos de cada una de las hojas. Encontre el siguiente codigo que me da el resultado esperado :

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D15")) Is Nothing Then

   'En base al campo Region de la Tabla dinámica1:
  With PivotTables("TablaTransacciones").PivotFields("Faenas")
     
       'Filtrar por el valor de la celda F1
     On Error Resume Next
        .CurrentPage = Range("D15").Value
        
   End With
End If
```

Ahora el problema que tengo es que al momento no de no tener datos, la tabla dinámica me deja como filtro "Todos" y se expande hasta el infinito.
Existirá alguna manera de que al momento de no tener el valor(Celda D15) en el filtro de la tabla dinámica , me busque un dato en la celda "E27" que es donde tengo el valor "sin datos" para el filtro de la tabla.

Muchas Gracias!!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Seguramente añadiendo la parte `Else` al IF inicial que tienes abierto. [Usar instrucciones If…Then…Else](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-ifthenelse-statements)